# mysql replication: replicate all but one table to different database on different server

Tags: mysql, replication

I got `database1` on `server1` and `database2` on `server2`.

Now I need to replicate a single table from `database1` to `database2`

Now I thought that this would work:

```
  replicate-ignore-table  = %
  replicate-do-table      = table
  replicate-rewrite-db    = "database1->database2"
```

but this does not seem to work as mysql does not accept `%` symbol with `replicate-ignore-table` directive. any ideas ?

EDIT:

I have tried :

```
  replicate-ignore-table  = database1.%
  replicate-do-table      = database1.table
  replicate-rewrite-db    = "database1->database2"
```

Now mysql is starting, but table is not being replicated.

Comment: +1 for answering you own question with a bit of lunch time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I had some lunch and figured it out !

```
  replicate-do-table      = database2.table
  replicate-rewrite-db    = "database1->database2"
```

Comment: I am glad to figured this one out yourself. I have something to share with you: `replicate-ignore-table` and `replicate-do-table` cannot be mixed any more than scotch and blood pressure meds. ( See my ServerFault post http://serverfault.com/a/271588/69271 under possibility #6 along with http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-rules-db-options.html ) You get a +1 for removing `replicate-ignore-table  = database1.%` to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
replicate-ignore-table  = database1.%
replicate-do-table      = database1.table
replicate-rewrite-db    = "database1->database2"
```

due to what you configured and refer to MySQL docs, the mistake in your configuration is that, you are rewriting the db (which will done before any replication rule) 1->2, and then filtering replication on DB1.

> check replication execution rules, flow [chart](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-rules-db-options.html).